# Creating a CSS look so a button acts like a checkbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a design from a graphic artists and i have successfully created the button that acts like a checkbox, however i cant seem to figure out the CSS to mimic the design. Its grey but on hover/click(checked) it changes color. I'm using bootstrap and fontawesome to try and achieve this.

IMG of functionality im trying to replicate:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/nojil/Lskdcu6r/31/

```css
#canvasBranch-ck-button {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ff4c00;
  border-color: #ff4c00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label span.iconSpan {
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  color: #fff;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button input:checked+span.textSpan {
  color: #ff4c00 !important;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button input:checked+span.iconSpan {
  background-color: #ff4c00;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasBranch-ck-button">
  <label class="d-flex mb-0">
        <input type="checkbox" value="canvasBranch">
        <span class="flex-fill align-items-center iconSpan"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
        <span class="align-items-center flex-fill textSpan">Canvas Branch</span>
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using anything like Bootstrap for styling or are you creating this on your own?

Comment: @bspeagle using bootstrap, i updated the jsfiddle

Comment: In CSS, `+` is the "**adjacent** sibling combinator", meaning it only applies if the given items are directly beside eachother. Your checkbox and `textSpan` are *not* adjacent siblings, therefore this will not work: `input:checked + span.textSpan`. You'll want to use the regular sibling combinator instead: `input:checked ~ span.textSpan`

Comment: @TylerRoper im getting close but check out the latest jsfiddle. I cant seem to get the iconspan to turn oj on hover and then the border color to turn oj on checked https://jsfiddle.net/nojil/Lskdcu6r/36/

Comment: @Charles Given the structure of your HTML, this is not possible without JavaScript. You cannot style a *parent* based on a *child*, therefore you won't be able to format the `<div>` based on the checkbox. They would have to be *siblings* instead. You may have to re-think your HTML.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks!

Comment: @Charles You got it. What I'd suggest is to start from scratch, but consider the `<label>` to be the parent of everything. Put whatever nested items you need inside there instead. You *can* change children based on the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you've shown an attempt, I figured I could throw you a bone here and give you a bit of an idea of how this might be implemented.

The issue you've run into, that I've explained in my comments, is that you're trying to style a parent (the `<div>`) based on the status (checked/unchecked) of a *child*, which cannot be done in CSS.

Given the use of `::before`, you could also implement icon-specific styling. You'll notice how I implemented them using the `.money` and `.question` class, and the only declaration necessary would be `content: 'x'`. You can [do this with Font-Awesome](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) too.

Consider something like this instead. Of course, you'll need to update the fonts and whatnot.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 170px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

label::before {
  width: 35px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  content: '!';
  text-align: center;
}

label.money::before {
  content: '$';
}

label.question::before {
  content: '?';
}

label>.text {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
}

label:hover,
input:checked+label {
  border: 1px solid #ff4c00;
}

label:hover>.text,
input:checked+label>.text {
  color: #ff4c00;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: white;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #ff4c00;
}
```

```html
<input class="hidden" id="chk1" type="checkbox">
<label class="" for="chk1">
  <span class="text">GENERIC</span>
</label>

<input class="hidden" id="chk2" type="checkbox">
<label class="money" for="chk2">
  <span class="text">MONEY</span>
</label>

<input class="hidden" id="chk3" type="checkbox">
<label class="question" for="chk3">
  <span class="text">QUESTION</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Why not use `::before` instead of two additional `span` elements?

Comment: Because then re-using this button style would require a bunch of specific classes for content. I suppose if the `$` portion was going to be re-used, that could be a pseudo.

Comment: Which you would do with a simple CSS class on the checkbox. Or the label. Or a parent wrapper, if you want that.

Comment: I understand the reason for the `$` element, but you suggested "instead of **two** additional `span` elements". Using a pseudo for the second span (the text), would require you to have to create a unique class for every single button to declare a new `content: 'Button Text'`, which seems silly and counter-intuitive. You'd end up with a style-sheet full of single-use-case button classes. I'll update the first to be a pseudo though.

Answer (score 1):

As @TylerRopper mention on the comment *You cannot style a parent based on a child* but you can always fake it, here it is:

```
<div id="canvasBranch-ck-button">
      <label class="d-flex mb-0">

        <input type="checkbox" value="canvasBranch">
        <span class="flex-fill align-items-center iconSpan"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
        <span class="align-items-center flex-fill textSpan">Canvas Branch</span>
         <div class="fakeborder">
         </div>
      </label>
```

Css

```
#canvasBranch-ck-button {
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

#fakeborder{
  width:150px;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #ff4c00;
    border-color: #ff4c00;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label span {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    display: block;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label span.iconSpan {
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    color: #fff;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button input:checked ~ span.textSpan {
    color: #ff4c00 !important;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button input:checked ~ span.iconSpan {
    background-color: #ff4c00;
}

#canvasBranch-ck-button input:checked ~ .fakeborder {
    border: 2px solid #ff4c00;
    width:151px;
    height: 32px;
    margin:-1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whatatimetobealive/oz4m7r92/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a starting point and customize to your likings.

```js
cb1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(cb1.checked)
})
```

```css
.cb-btn {
  display: none;
}

.cb-btn + label {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0.5em 5px 2.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.cb-btn:not(:checked + label):hover {
  border-color: #a00;
  color: #a00;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.cb-btn + label::before {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "$ ";
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 2em;
}

.cb-btn:not(:checked) + label:hover::before {
  background-color: #a00;
  color: #fff;
}

.cb-btn:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0.5em 5px 2.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.cb-btn:checked + label::before {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="canvasBranch" id="cb1" class="cb-btn">
<label class="d-flex mb-0" for="cb1">Label Text</label>
```