# clicking a button inside a label does not trigger the respective input

Tags: html, dom

I'm trying to change the style of a `checkbox` by hiding it and adding a button inside it's parent label like this:

```html
<label onclick="console.log('label received click event')">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" onchange="console.log('input value changed')">
  <button type="button">click here</button>
</label>
```

But clicking on the button doesn't trigger the input.
This setup works if I use a `div` instead of a `button`:

```html
<label onclick="console.log('label received click event')">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" onchange="console.log('input value changed')">
  <div>click here</div>
</label>
```

Which is expected and also matches the [label documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). What I don't understand is that in both cases the `click` event is being bubbled up to the label, so the label receives the click event. What's special about button that is different with the `div` or other elements? And is there a way to make it work?

PS: I also tried to do a `event.preventDefault()` on the `button` but it didn't change the anything.

Comment: a label is an element to label a single input element. It is not for labeling multiple elements

Comment: @tacoshy the goal is not to label multiple elements with one `label`, but only to input the input. You can have a `span` along with an `img` or `i` element in the label which help to shape the aesthetics of the label. But it doesn't work with `button` and I'm trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of behaviour, please do not wrap more than one element in a label.

Also please consider screen readers may behave differently than you expect when you are messing with the normal UI

A button certainly does not need a label and you have MUCH simpler code if you just do

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" style="display: none" 
  onchange="console.log('input value changed')">Label for checkbox</label>
```

If you want to style the button as a checkbox you can do

[Creating a CSS look so a button acts like a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314691/creating-a-css-look-so-a-button-acts-like-a-checkbox)

which is just one of [hundreds of similar answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=style+checkbox+as+button+site:stackoverflow.com)

---

If you want to [style the label as a button](https://www.google.com/search?q=style+label+as+button+site:stackoverflow.com) then it could look like this

```css
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: "arial-black";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.button:hover{
    background: red;

}
```

```html
<label class="button"><input type="checkbox" style="display: none" 
  onchange="console.log('input value changed')">Label for checkbox</label>
```

Comment: Actually the goal is not to make the button look like a checkbox, but the other way around. And yes that's good advice not to put multiple elements in a label. The point of the question is however to find out what is the source of difference between the two different behaviors.

Comment: Sorry, You are trying to make a button check the checkbox! It is exactly what I posted. How is that "the other way around"? Also why do you care how invalid HTML triggers JavaScript when all you have to do is to make it valid

Comment: See update.....

Comment: Thanks for the answer and update. Yes I also in the meantime changed my implementation to something similar to your second snippet. But what I'm trying to figure out is the behavior and reasoning behind that. You mentioned `invalid HTML`, is there somewhere in the specs where it says having multiple elements in a label is invalid? I couldn't find a notion of that so far.

Comment: [HTML Spec: Content model:
Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-label-element)
----
[MDN: Permitted content Phrasing content, but no descendant label elements. No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#technical_summary)

Comment: I've already read those two documents before reaching out to SO (in fact linked to one already in my question)
Unfortunately couldn't find any explanation about the mentioned behavior. Thanks for the links anyways.

Comment: Did you read the sentences I pasted. They answer your question exactly.